# How to get some advantages of dynamic loading on embedded systems?

Tags: embedded, bootloader, linker

Some experiential context: The majority of my professional coding is on either baremetal or RTOS embedded systems, while most of my teaching has to do with Linux hosted code. One thing I deeply miss when on an embedded system is a dynamic loader, i.e. ld.so.

Having a similar system on embedded would be great. I could provide things like board support code and drivers in a bootloader. The application code could then be dynamically loaded and call these functions. The application would thus not need to be so closely coupled to hardware. This could have the positive devOps effect of keeping board-level differences and application changes nicely separated. Think N+M versions instead of N*M, where N and M are variations in hardware and application respectively. Such a solution could also reduce repeated code between the bootloader (which must stand alone) and the application (which needn't). E.g. the application could ask the bootloader to call printf.

How much pain am I looking at if I want to replicate the basic features of ld.so on an embedded system? Those basic features being:

- Load position-independent code from some library file. It needn't be a 'real' .so.
- A library may sometimes be a file provided from a host computer instead of the embedded system's own FS, more like a firmware updater.
- Call functions in the loaded libraries.
- Call, from a loaded library, functions that are provided by other libraries or the bootloader. The bootloader in this case acts like an operating system and abstracts the board hardware.
- Indirectly protect the application programmer from having to worry about absurd board-level and MCU-specific shenanigans (I ought to help myself by helping someone else)

Does such a system already exist in the wild? Would it be too unreasonable to try and port the real ld.so to do this? My intuition is that this idea is right on the border between being useful and too difficult to be worth it.

Comment: Hello and welcome ... an interesting idea ... could you illustrate what sorts of CPUs you're speaking about?

Comment: An Arm system with Flash and SRAM, around 32M/1M in size respectively. Crucially it will have no MMU and thus cannot run Linux, but it can run an RTOS such as FreeRTOS. The application requires preemptive multitasking.

Comment: @AaronLinnell I like that you've limited your hardware. Improves the focus. I also understand the idea of isolating the MCU-specific and board-specific details, when teaching, though I wonder if avoiding the pain may lead to still more difficult mental struggles for students when they later may face situations where the ARM MCU I/O initialization code changes from IC stepping to IC stepping and have no idea why certain things aren't working, anymore. I get it about pre-emption. Though teaching cooperative should come slightly earlier, my opinion. What's the topic title being taught?

Comment: I'm not teaching this specific idea. The values I predict this having are more to do with development and maintenance benefits in a engineering job that has multiple products with overlapping functionality.

Comment: It sounds more like you "really" want a BIOS.  So use system traps or a table of known vectors to functions in the BIOS to access all the common functions, and let your boot/BIOS code be responsible for making it actually happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have dynamic loading your first need to have loading... Many embedded platforms run the code directly from flash or ROM, they do not load the code in RAM to execute it.

What you are talking about seems to rather be either a BIOS, an OS, [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call), a [hardware abstraction layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_abstraction#In_operating_systems), drivers or even a standard library (or a combination of the above).

If I understand your need, a simple way to do this would be for the "bootloader" to include all these functions you want with a platform-independent interface (API). Then you have a table at a fixed location in that bootloader with the addresses of all those functions, and in your code, you just call the function through that pointer.

So for instance you would say that at 0x1000 you will find the address of "printf", at 0x1002 the address of "set_io_high", at 0x1004 the address of "set_io_low", etc. You would need an information somewhere about the number of available calls or the version of the table, so you don't try to call functions which aren't available.

Alternatively, you could have a single fixed address of a function to call, and in the arguments to that function there would be the number of the function.

Note however that it is probably not a good idea to include so much stuff in the bootloader itself. You want the bootloader to be as simple and small as possible (less risks for bugs and ending up with a bricked device), and require the least possible updates. So it would probably be more bootloader -> additional layer -> application.

Some embedded platforms already have similar mechanisms for some features, like the ["softdevices" on the Nordic nRF5 platform](https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fug_gsg_ses%2FUG%2Fgsg%2Fsoftdevices.html) which provide some of the wireless functionality and can be updated independently from the rest of the application code.

But really, in the case of embedded, there are so many other things which require separate builds anyway (processor type/architecture, flash/ROM/RAM/SPI RAM/etc, addresses...) that I think it's more likely you need to address this on the build side of things than on the device itself. Even devices in the same family often require separate builds.

Answer (score 2):

tl; dr: Yes, it's possible, but with great flexibility comes great responsibility to ensure your system remains reliable. In a constrained platform like yours it probably isn't worth it. Better to constrain the desired flexibility in a sandbox that can't kill the rest of your system.

Many smaller RTOSs support dynamic modules. But given that memory is cheap while for-pay RTOSs cost, well, money, it’s no wonder that folks opt for Linux, BSD and other free-as-in-speech alternatives and pay a bit more for hardware that can run them.

The motivation for dynamic loading has as much to do with managing limited RAM memory resources as it does with being able to configure your run-time per platform. Otherwise, why bother? For a very small platform without an RTOS (or even with one), you just build your image with the modules you need and be done with it. While this seems unwieldy, in reality it better contains the QA problem when you have a known, tested 'golden image' that has gone through a proper software QA process. Any memory leaks, deadlocks, or other issues will have hopefully been flushed out prior to dropping the image.

If I haven't convinced you otherwise, and still want to dynamically load modules as needed (that is, your system is ‘modal’), consider the kinds of bugs that can occur and how to approach them, not just in your design, but in your QA process as well.

Say you grow your system to having a full-featured OS with a file system, dynamic loading and other support. This enhances flexibility, but it also comes with downsides such as garbage collection (if you allow it - it would be a definite no-no with an RTOS expected to meet hard deadlines) and other problems like memory leaks.

Problems like these even come up with commercial embedded RTOSs, such as the Pathfinder Mars Rover running VxWorks (a well-regarded, but expensive commercial RTOS) that became unresponsive due to an out-of-memory bug: https://www.computerworld.com/article/2574759/out-of-memory-problem-caused-mars-rover-s-glitch.html

Or worse, when a bad RTOS-based design kills someone because a critical thread quits running: https://www.autosafety.org/wp-content/uploads/import/Bookout%20PDF.pdf

Which brings up something else to think about. A new language, Rust, avoids many memory bugs that creep in to typical C/C++ based platforms. One major plus: Rust doesn’t use garbage collection. More here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch00-00-introduction.html

Comment: You seem to be saying that the Linux, BSD etc don't have dynamic loading: in what sense is that?

Comment: I’m saying the exact opposite: of course Linux et. al. have dynamic loading. But what if your platform is too small to run such an OS? Then you need to think about whether you could run a smaller RTOS which could do it, or if not, even if dynamic loading makes sense vs. a prebuilt image.

Comment: Ah now I understood what you meant about memory -- it's not that Linux etc don't have dynamic memory, it's they're not small.  What does "free as in beer" mean?  Is it a US saying for something that costs money?

Comment: Maybe this will explain things: https://www.howtogeek.com/31717/what-do-the-phrases-free-speech-vs.-free-beer-really-mean/

Comment: Wrt. your note about model systems. The device is modal only as far as manufacturer provisioning goes. The goal is to make changes of hardware or application easier for us (the manufacturer) as many of our applications can use similar hardware. Above a certain complexity threshold one could just use a Linux SoM, so this solution I seek is mainly for "intermediate" systems, somewhere between a microwave and a (modern, smart) printer. I propose this is still a broad genus of devices ;)

Comment: There is one other advantage I seek which is quite specific to my field. Often customers will want slightly different behavior to better integrate into their existing setups. Releasing a new software version to do this creates a lot of work down the line for maintaining. If features were better segmented into libraries, e.g. a library for communication or remote management, these features could be provided in a more flexible form... assuming good initial interface design of course.

Comment: @hacktastical thanks for link ... respectfully I think "zero-price" is an expression likely to be better understood, though I see you've edited the question to the opposite meaning.

Comment: The distinction is between software given away for free (e.g., Acrobat Reader) but nonetheless with restrictive licensing (can't alter, can't redistribute without permission), vs. open-source which has licensing that allows such things. While both are 'zero-price', only the latter allows customization. And yes, I edited my text to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

Just to provide some explanation why dynamic-anything is usually frowned upon in embedded systems: it is because they are usually much higher integrity systems than your average Linux one.

High integrity, high quality embedded systems are characterized by:

- A high level of determinism. Nothing unexpected is allowed to happen.
- All code in the program may be executed at some point. No dead code exists.
- Only does what the design was intended for. Tight coupling between requirements and the code, so that there should be no code in the firmware which cannot get tied to a certain requirement.
- Is tailor-made for specific requirements related to the intended environment.
- Picks parts, tools and technologies to suit the requirements. Rather than picking a part/tool/technology in advance and then try to shoe-horn in the requirements. As in, pick something in order to solve a specific problem, do not pick something in order to create a solution to an undefined or non-existing problem.
- Often comes with high performance and real-time requirements, meaning it has to be efficient and slim. Whereas generic programming always comes with a lot of overhead.
- The [KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle), rather than "complicate things just for the heck of it". It has been proven in studies of software that the amount of undiscovered bugs and complexity follow each other pretty much like a linear function.

The problem of having different configurations for such systems are typically never solved by swapping out the executable code, but instead by providing different data sets (for example programmed in data flash/eeprom).

*Not* swapping out the code has the big advantage that all tests of code coverage, coding standards, static analysis, code review and so on need not get carried out over and over. Instead you can design tests covering all possible (and impossible) combinations of data sets.

For scenarios where you do want to change the code for whatever reason, different versions/builds of the code are handled with version control - hence the name. Resulting in one single binary executable. Then you just flash the whole MCU at once using single-wire interfaces such as SWD/JTAG. No need for icky, error-prone bootloaders that realistically will also require you to include a lot of checksums in the binary.

Comment: OP wants to be able to configure systems late in the production process. That said, yes, a high-integrity system should be configured and tested with an appropriate software QA process prior to release, especially if it has some critical requirements like functional safety. This would apply whether it's pre-built and statically linked, or if it has modules loaded and dynamically linked. Also, part of checking the integrity of the system would be to use signed code, which gets more complicated (but not impossible) with dynamic modules.

Answer (score 1):

*I'm not sure that EE.SE is the best place for this, but it's a very interesting topic much more applicable to board-level designers than software engineers in general.*

If I was to do this, I certainly wouldn't start with current ld.so, though that is of course possible.  I know of nothing readily available for what you're describing, but am thinking about what would be necessary to build a minimal one, if coding near bare metal.

All of the following is just a sketch of a possible system based on how to get rid of "updating of addresses" (conventional linking) with "finding my modules".

One way to approach this is to rewind to how we did things before it was routine for computers to have memory-management units and many megabytes of memory.  There are four principal issues with the conventional dynamic linking-loader: 1) Relocation, 2) Linking of modules, 3) Potential sharing of modules, 4) Engineering.

Most of the current systems are based on GNU's tools in one way or another, and even in its early days porting GCC could be tricky if your architecture didn't match.  Thsi is a large set of programs, designed to construct large programs efficiently.  Specifically it doesn't not have simplicity as one of its primary goals.

If we start with simpler ideas it might be more practical.

My thoughts are: a chain of position-independent library modules, with a defined inter-module interface.

Although module linking and relocation share some features (filling in addresses we didn't know or which might have changed), they are quite different problems.

**1.  Relocation**

Let's imagine you completely eliminate relocation, by writing or getting your compiler to produce **position-independent code**.  Thus each module can be put anywhere in memory and still function without any relocation.  (Article about [PIC on ARM](https://community.arm.com/arm-community-blogs/b/tools-software-ides-blog/posts/easy-as-pie----creating-bare-metal-position-independent-executables-with-arm-compiler-6))

**2. Linking of Modules**

We can borrow from the early microcomputer days, where additional features were often sold as **expansion ROMs**.  One of the best examples of this was Motorola's 6839 Floating Point "Unit", which is exactly the kind of library module we might want to update.

It's a ROM containing position independent code for the 6809, an 8-bit processor from the 1980s with 16-bit addresses.  The ROM has a fixed jump-table at the beginning for the functions.

[image]
From Motorola via Jeff Tranter [github project](https://github.com/jefftranter/6809/blob/master/sbc/mc6839/docs/MC6839%20Floating-point%20ROM%20Datasheet.pdf).

**3. Loading and sharing of modules**

It was common for a base system to search all of address space for a magic number for identifying its expansion ROMs.  Much better is some defined way to add them in.

Motorola published a boot ROM with a monitor program, ASSIST09, which looked for an extension in this exact way; it also provided basic BIOS calls such as `INCH` and `OUTCH` (input/output a character) which were executed by a software interrupt followed by a function ID, pretty much the way systems calls were always done.  (See Motorola's [6809 Programming Manual](http://www.bitsavers.org/components/motorola/6809/M6809PM.rev0_May83.pdf), Appendix B for description and listing.)

We could either a) always find our necessary modules and load them with the program, or b) have some kind of shared-across-all programs mechanism.

Perhaps based on an interface like this:

- Each module has a unique module ID and a version
- It can publish its shared functions
- It can ask for modules by ID and version
- Every program's `crt0` executes a get-my-modules call, fails if no such library available
- Each inter-module function call is through a stub which indirects through tables

I'm imagining some structures along these lines, though the details would depend a lot on the your memory layout and what kind of run-time error reporting is possible.

```
struct module {
    unsigned int id;
    unsigned int version;
    struct functiontable {
        int n;
        struct function {
            unsigned int id;
            void (*fn)(void);
        }
    } *functable;
    struct module *next;
} *moduleroot;
```

Inside the main program, you have a stub like this:

```
int putchar(int c) {
    return (thislibrary[FUNC_PUTCHAR])(c)
}
```

**4.  Engineering**

Obviously, it's non-trivial.  Whether it's difficult depends on how many other things you need to interface to, how much control you have over the libraries, how easy it is for your organisation to maintain the ABI -- all those module IDs, all those function IDs -- and how the modules get from flash to RAM.

If you can get hold of one of ARM's software interrupts you can generate a run-time linking mechanism which is pretty general and reduces the per-module overhead, but a lot of the detail depends on other issues.